# Two apps with same display names in Google Play

Tags: google-play

Six months ago I published my first app to Google Play. It was simple game like 4 pics 1 word. It became very popular in my country (Russia).

Now I want to release the same game but with different levels.

I try to add new app in my Google play developer console but I get the following message:

> You need to choose a different title for your app. This one is already
>   the title of com.hungl.photosandwords.

I want to publish my new game with exectly same name as the first one.
Is it possible?

I have two ideas about it:

1) Choose default language as English (my game isn't translated in English) and add translation to Russian. But won't it affect in search position?

2) Use other account to publish new game. But I'm afraid I'll get banned for the same design.

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, I guess.

Take a look at this:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html